# How to get the call count using Mock @patch?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am writing a unit test for some library we are working on. This library makes use of `requests.post()` to perform POST HTTP requests to an external server.

Inside my UT, I obviously don't want to contact the real server but to mock the response.

To do that, I wrote a function that goes like:

```
def mocked_post(url, headers, data, **kwargs):
    response = Mock()

    # Some logic, irrelevant here.

    return response
```

And I patched this function around my unit test class:

```
@patch('mylib.requests.post', mocked_post)
class MyTest(TestCase):

    def test_foo(self):
        # Some test logic
```

This is working perfectly.

Now I'd like to get the number of calls to my mocked function. I tried `mocked_post.call_count` but that doesn't exist. I tried to find this property on a lot of different objects (including `mylib.requests.post`) but no luck so far.

How can I access the `call_count` for this mocked function ?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I'd not use `mocked_post` as the `new` argument here. I'd set up the [`side_effect` attribute](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.Mock.side_effect) of a fresh `Mock` instead:

```
@patch('mylib.requests.post')
class MyTest(TestCase):

    def test_foo(self, post_mock):
        post_mock.side_effect = mocked_post

        # Some test logic

        self.assertEqual(post_mock.call_count, 3)
```

Now you have the `Mock` object that `patch` generates for you as an argument to all your test methods, and you can thus test how many times that mock was called.

You should be able to set the `side_effect` attribute in the decorator as well, to apply to all tests:

```
@patch('mylib.requests.post', side_effect=mocked_post)
class MyTest(TestCase):

    def test_foo(self, post_mock):
        # Some test logic

        self.assertEqual(post_mock.call_count, 3)
```

You'll still have trouble accessing the returned `response` object, however; you may want to return `mock.DEFAULT` from `mocked_post` instead of creating one in the function, so that you can then use `post_mock.return_value` to make further assertions on the returned object.

Comment: This works indeed perfectly. Many thanks. However, I'm not sure to understand why we must affect `mocked_post` to something named `side_effect`. Doesn't seem like a *side effect* to me but rather like the main purpose of the mocked object. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @ereOn: `side_effect` is overloaded here; returning `mock.DEFAULT` instead would make it clearer perhaps what `side_effect` is doing. It is being called every time the mock is called, and as a side effect can have influence on what is returned but that's not required.

Comment: Indeed, makes sense. Now I get it. Thanks again for your very thorough answer and clear explanations.

Answer (score 3):

Coming 9 years later but you can also do :

```
   @patch('mylib.requests.post')
   class MyTest(TestCase):

      def test_foo(self, post_mock):
        # Some test logic

        assert post_mock.call_count == 3

        #if you need to mock the return value
        post_mock.return_value = "success"
```